# Why does python's recursive copy not work the same as on the command line?

Tags: python, linux, directory, cp, os.system

I'm trying to do a recursive copy of a directory structure in my python script. When I do the copy via the bash command line:

```
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/head$ cp -rf ./applications/app_template/ ./applications/my_dir
```

I get the expected results:

```
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/head$ tree ./applications/my_dir/
./applications/my_dir/
├── cdl
│   ├── include
│   ├── Makefile
│   ...
│   └── other
├── cds
│   ├── include
...
```

However when I try to do the same thing via my Python script:

```
print "./applications/"+tar_dir
os.system("cp -rf ./applications/app_template/ ./applications/"+tar_dir)
```

I get:

```
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/head$ tree ./applications/my_dir/
./applications/my_dir/
└── app_template         <--- why did it copy that too?
    ├── cdl
    │   ├── include
    │   ├── Makefile
    │   ...
    │   └── other
    ├── cds
    │   ├── include
    ...
```

My python script's print is showing me that I'm using the same target:

```
./applications/my_dir
```

And you can see the rest of my command is the same. So why do I get a different output when using `os.system()` than I do when I run my command directly from the shell?

Comment: perhaps `os.system` uses a different shell than what you're using. Maybe the problem will be solved by using `subprocess`, where you can specify which shell to use

Comment: @inspectorG4dget - An interesting idea... do you know how I can check what exactly the os.system call is doing?

Comment: Try os.system("echo $0")

Comment: If in the second case the target directory already existed, while it didn't in the first, then this behaviour would be expected... Are you sure that's not the case?

Comment: @mata - An excellent thought, but what actually happens in that case (I just tried) is that you see `cdl`, `cds`, etc AND `app_template` all in the same directory. Not what I'm seeing in my case. I've been running `rm -rf ./applications/my_dir` in between every test, so it is really gone

Comment: @PauloAlmeida - Seems you're on to *something*... but it's not quite there. When I check my shell on the command line it's `bash`, when I check it vis the os.system call it's `sh`. So the `os.system` is changing my shell, but even when I switch to `sh` and run the command it works as I would expect

Answer (score 0):

Seems `os.system` changes the shell it executes in to `sh`:

```
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/head$ echo $0
bash

mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/head$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15) 
>>> import os
>>> os.system("echo $0")
sh
```

When the copy command is executed via Popen with a bash shell, it works as expected:

```
>>> import subprocess as sp
>>> sp.Popen("cp -rf ./applications/icom_app_template ./applications/my_dir", 
              shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
>>> exit()
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/head$ tree ./applications/my_dir/
./applications/my_dir/
├── cdl
│   ├── include
│   ├── Makefile
│   ...
│   └── other
├── cds
│   ├── include
...
```

The only oddity that I do not have an answer for is that if I switch to the `sh` shell on the command line (outside of Python) and execute the same `cp` command, it works without copying the parent "template" directory. Strange... but switching to `Popen` and forcing a `bash` shell seems to fix my problem.